# jquery terminal submit command without pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, terminal, jquery-terminal

How can i submit a command without pressing the enter button?
I need to make the terminal recognize the speech (that part is already done) and visualize it like a command, than virtually press enter to get an ajax response, is it possible? thanks

Comment: `$( "target" ).click()`?

Comment: Hello almanegra, actually i need a command to execute without clicking but calling a function in jquery terminal.

Comment: I believe there is a native command like "push", but i don't know how to use it. This is the reference http://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php there are just a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

push create new interpreter when you have new prompt and new set of commands, to execute the command you can use exec:

```
term.exec('command');
```

it will echo the command and execute your command (if you pass true as second argument it will not echo prompt and command being executed), for instancec if you have:

```
var term = $('...').terminal({
  foo: function() {
    this.echo('foo');
  }
});

term.exec('foo');
```

will execute your foo function.

or you can simulate keydown event for enter:

```
var e = $.Event("keydown");
e.ctrlKey = ctrl;
e.altKey = alt;
e.shiftKey = shift;
e.which = e.keyCode = 13;
$(document.documentElement || window).trigger(e);
```

if you're adding text using `term.insert('word');` it will be better to use key down event.

**EDIT**: key down event may not work with a recent version of jQuery Terminal to trigger the event with jQuery events look at [Jest tests](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/master/__tests__/terminal.spec.js).